# How to use getoptlong with variable options?

Tags: ruby, nagios

I have a couple Nagios scripts which inherit a common NagiosCheck class. Since every check has slightly different getopts options I thought it'd be the best to generate the available options via a NagiosCheck class method. But I'm stuck...

This is how I call the method:

```
class CheckFoobar < NagiosCheck
  ...
end

check = CheckFoobar.new
check.generate_options(
  ['-H', '--hostname', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT],
  ['-P', '--port', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT],
  ['-u', '--url', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT])
```

The method itself:

```
class NagiosCheck
  ...
  def generate_options (*args)
    options = []

    args.each do |arg|
      options << arg
    end

    parser = GetoptLong.new
    options.each {|arg| parser.set_options(arg)}
  end
end
```

Then parser only stores the last item:

```
p parser # => #<GetoptLong:0x00000000e17dc8 @ordering=1, @canonical_names={"-u"=>"-u", "--url"=>"-u"}, @argument_flags={"-u"=>1, "--url"=>1}, @quiet=false, @status=0, @error=nil, @error_message=nil, @rest_singles="", @non_option_arguments=[]>
```

1. Do you have any advice for me how to get parser to store all arguments?

Regards,
Mike

... First question here on stackoverflow. Please bear with me if I did something wrong and let me know so that I'm able to adapt.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I wish all first questions were as well crafted as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generate_options method is too complex. Getoptlong.new takes an array of arrays as argument.

```
class NagiosCheck
  def generate_options (*args)
     GetoptLong.new(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for being late with my answer. Thank you, that's what I needed to know! An array of arrays, quite confusing in the first place.